# Can the conceptual metaphor be approached syntactically?

Tags: syntax, resource-request, online-resources, cognitive-linguistics, metaphor

I am really interested in studying how syntax is connected to cognition. I would like to see if the conceptual nature of metaphor can also be approached syntactically. But I don't know where to start. Could you maybe name some resources (academic papers), or provide any type of guidance?

Comment: Probably syntax is not the appropriate model; syntax is for representing linear temporal events like speech. Metaphor is a matter of framing and lexical selection in appropriate pragmatic contexts. For instance, [the _`Time` Is `Money`_ metaphor theme](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Lakoff and Johnson discuss possible relationships between metaphor and syntax in their 1980 book *Metaphors We Live By*. Their focus is mostly on understanding syntax through the framework of metaphor, rather than the other way around, and some of their examples have been disproven rather thoroughly (like the claim that WITH-accompaniment and WITH-instrument are always the same in every language), but it's still a decent starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think the association of syntax with the conceptual metaphor would be a good research paper topic?

Comment: Sure. Look at the metaphors in Relational (aka Arc Pair) Grammar, in contrast to the ones in MITis theories. One uses economic terms (promote, demote, _en chômage_) and the other uses social ones (daughter, sister, head, parent, command, dominate). For instance.